# How should I go about creating safe, encrypted password in Clojure?

Tags: security, encryption, clojure

I'm building a web application. Among other fields in the table User, there are: enc_passw and salt. What's the idiomatic way to create a hashed/encrypted password in Clojure? What are the most trustworthy and decent libraries?

Also, should I just concatenate the real password and salt to  calculate  hashed/encrypted password? For example:

```
(secure_hash (str "my_real_pass" "my_salt"))
```

Comment: See [buddy](https://github.com/funcool/buddy).  In particular, I would not use a separate salt field, and instead just use the functionality in [buddy.hashers](https://funcool.github.io/buddy-hashers/latest/).

Comment: @CurtisSummers, "buddy"  provides a lot of functionality I don't need.

Comment: You can use `buddy-hashers` separately from the other buddy libraries.  It's a small wrapper around [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/) crypto hashing.

Comment: @CurtisSummers, tnx. Where does buddy.hashers store a salt?

Comment: buddy concatenates the algorithm name, salt, iterations, and hash into a single string delimited by `$`, which gives it everything it needs to check against a password and only requires a single database field.  This method also allows you to evolve to the best crypto functions without having to re-tool your db fields.  It also has a convenient [rehash hook](https://funcool.github.io/buddy-hashers/latest/#rehash-hook) to update password hashes with newer ones.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at friend's credential implementation [here](https://github.com/cemerick/friend/blob/master/src/cemerick/friend/credentials.clj).

It's using `[org.mindrot/jbcrypt "0.3m"]`.

```
(defn hash-bcrypt
  "Hashes a given plaintext password using bcrypt and an optional
    :work-factor (defaults to 10 as of this writing).  Should be used to hash
    passwords included in stored user credentials that are to be later verified
    using `bcrypt-credential-fn`."
   [password & {:keys [work-factor]}]
   (BCrypt/hashpw password (if work-factor
                             (BCrypt/gensalt work-factor)
                             (BCrypt/gensalt))))
```

If you want an argumentation on `bcrypt`, read coda's [here](https://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/)

Comment: It's probably worth quoting your links portion on why salts aren't needed, since that's a shift in password security protocols, I believe. Either way, good answer.